# Merging 2 dfs using string contains and multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DFs that I want to merge. but I need to merge them based on a string contains and also using multiple columns

df_1

```
    IN          Start_Time          Description                                                                     Per_Extr
0   IN7305517   2022-07-24 00:06:59 ABEND JOB PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D and JOB_STREAM_NAME P26_BRAI_RS2...      FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
1   IN7305465   2022-07-24 00:09:49 ABEND JOB PP_AAAR_4898_POUP_MOV_TDCH_D and JOB_STREAM_NAME P26_AAAR_006_TSA...  FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
2   IN7305466   2022-07-24 00:10:16 ABEND JOB PP_AAAR_4898_POUPMOV_D and JOB_STREAM_NAME P26_AAAR_006_TSA...        FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
3   IN7305493   2022-07-24 00:20:27 ABEND JOB PP_BGDTPRODHBACMS102020_01_M and JOB_STREAM_NAME P26_BGDTDCHF_PUM...  FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
```

df_2

```
    JOB_STREAM_NAME     JOB_NAME
NaN P26_BRAI_RS2        PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D
NaN P26_BRAI_VAR_TOD    PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D
NaN P26_AAAR_006_TSA    PP_AAAR_4898_POUP_MOV_TDCH_D
NaN P26_AAAR_006_TSA    PP_AAAR_4898_POUPMOV_D
NaN P26_BGDTDCHF_PUM    PP_BGDTPRODHBACMS102020_01_M
```

The description column has the JOB_NAME and JOB_STREAM_NAME in it

What I'm aiming is a df like this:
merged_df

```
    IN          JOB_STREAM_NAME     JOB_NAME                        Start_Time          Description                                                                     Per_Extr
0   IN7305517   P26_BRAI_RS2        PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D    2022-07-24 00:06:59 ABEND JOB PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D and JOB_STREAM_NAME P26_BRAI_RS2...      FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
1   NaN         P26_BRAI_VAR_TOD    PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D    NaN                 NaN                                                                             NaN
2   IN7305465   P26_AAAR_006_TSA    PP_AAAR_4898_POUP_MOV_TDCH_D    2022-07-24 00:10:16 ABEND JOB PP_AAAR_4898_POUPMOV_D and JOB_STREAM_NAME P26_AAAR_006_TSA...        FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
3   IN7305466   P26_AAAR_006_TSA    PP_AAAR_4898_POUPMOV_D          2022-07-24 00:10:16 ABEND JOB PP_AAAR_4898_POUPMOV_D and JOB_STREAM_NAME P26_AAAR_006_TSA...        FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
4   IN7305493   P26_AAAR_006_TSA    PP_AAAR_4898_POUPMOV_D          2022-07-24 00:20:27 ABEND JOB PP_BGDTPRODHBACMS102020_01_M and JOB_STREAM_NAME P26_BGDTDCHF_PUM...  FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
```

Notice that the job PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D is in 2 JOB_STREAM_NAME and has no INs for one of them, that's why in the merged_df it appears without IN(NaN) for the one in the JOB_STREAM_NAME = P26_BRAI_VAR_TOD

I was instructed to do that with one column, but, not managing doing the same for multiple columns.

For one column I'm using this approach:

```
jobs_list= "|".join(map(str, df_2['JOB_NAME']))
new_df.insert(0, 'merge_key', df_1['Description'].str.extract("("+jobs_list+")", expand=False))
df_merged = new_df.merge(df_1, how='right', left_on='merge_key', right_on='JOB_NAME').drop('merge_key', axis=1)
```

could you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need a key to merge the two, so we extract the keys and use them to merge.

```
# extract the keys from the description and create addl columns
# you can always drop these afterwards

df[['JOB_NAME', 'JOB_STREAM_NAME' ]]=df['Description'].str.extract(r'JOB\s\b(\w+)\b.*?JOB_STREAM_NAME\s\b(\w+)\b' )

#merge on steam_name and job_name, since columns names are common, these won't be repeated
df3=df2.merge(df, on=['JOB_STREAM_NAME','JOB_NAME'], how='left')
df3

# drop the addl columns
df=df.drop(columns=['JOB_STREAM_NAME','JOB_NAME'])
```

```
    JOB_STREAM_NAME     JOB_NAME    IN  Start_Time  Description     Per_Extr
0   P26_BRAI_RS2    PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D    IN7305517   2022-07-24 00:06:59     ABEND JOB PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D and JOB...   FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
1   P26_BRAI_VAR_TOD    PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   P26_AAAR_006_TSA    PP_AAAR_4898_POUP_MOV_TDCH_D    IN7305465   2022-07-24 00:09:49     ABEND JOB PP_AAAR_4898_POUP_MOV_TDCH_D and JOB...   FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
3   P26_AAAR_006_TSA    PP_AAAR_4898_POUPMOV_D  IN7305466   2022-07-24 00:10:16     ABEND JOB PP_AAAR_4898_POUPMOV_D and JOB_STREA...   FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
4   P26_BGDTDCHF_PUM    PP_BGDTPRODHBACMS102020_01_M    IN7305493   2022-07-24 00:20:27     ABEND JOB PP_BGDTPRODHBACMS102020_01_M and JOB...   FROM : 2022/01/08 TO : 2022/12/09
```

```
(r'JOB\s  : match the literal JOB followed by \s (whitespace)
\b : word boundary
(\w+)\b : capture one or more letters followed by word boundary (that will be your jobid)
.*? : match one or letters (non greedy)
JOB_STREAM_NAME\s\b : match the literal followed by whitespace, followed by word boundary
(\w+)\b : capture one or more word characters followed by word boundary

' )
```

Comment: Hi @Naveed, that's almost what I need, but, one thing I'm not mentioning, not all the values in the Description fields are like I posted here, but, let me see if I can manage to use this suggestion

Comment: Regex used JOB and JOB_STREAM_NAME as a reference points in capturing the Job name and stream name, which are then used for merge. If you don't have both, how you like to merge? can one of them be used?

Comment: hey @Naveed the pattern is as follows in the Description column 
"TR26 U.A.C. >>> Abend in Job PP_BRAI_VAR_CARTAO_IND_IBI_D  from P26_BRAI_RS2"

Comment: yea and that is how you have the description in the question. right? solution is based on the pattern found in the question

Comment: yes, yes, just confirming...@Naveed, would you mind explaining what the regex is doing?  I know what is doing, but I don't know what is what in the command.

Comment: added the explanation in solution.